# Lambda function calling Codepipeline and passing parameters. Possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Has anyone ever tried or have examples of a python based Lambda function where I call a specific codepipeline, but I want to pass it variables in such a way that these variables are used during the Codebuild process?

I typically put in env variables during the codebuild process so I want to affect these.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Using the start_pipeline_execution call from boto3 (or any other AWS SDK) it is not possible to pass parameters to CodePipeline, because it is not supported by the [CodePipeline API][2].</s>



**Update**: This now suported and you can specify a list of variables with a pipeline execution e.g. with Python boto3.

```html
response = client.start_pipeline_execution(
    name='string',
    variables=[
        {
            'name': 'string',
            'value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    ...
)
```

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline/client/start_pipeline_execution.html#